# Need help with security review

Tags: managed-package, security-review, beta-managed-package

I have created a package and passed it for security review. The package passed the security review with flying colours!! All this time I installed the package in fresh org and I encountered no problems during installation. But after security review I installed the package in my personal developer org, but the package failed to install. Now I commented a line of code and created a new package. Does the new package need to be passed through security review again?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and install new package versions without each version going through a security review. The security review only needs to be done periodically.

So your problem has some other cause most likely related to the change you made.